# FB Graph API OAuthException error code 2500

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I fetch user's friend list using graph API, and it was working fine til yesterday. Now I am getting the following error while trying to get friends list:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

However `accessToken` are not expired. Is there any change in the api or am I doing anything wrong, which cause this error?

Comment: are you trying with localhost?can you tell more about the Fb JS codes here

Comment: No, I am trying with localhost, here is the url I am trying to hit:"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends&fields=id,picture,name,gender,birthday,email&access_token="

Comment: Updates to above we are not trying with localhost

Answer (score 0):

Ok,The Graph API allows you to easily access all `public` info about an object, however to get additional info beyond that, you must first get a user's permission.For this you need to fetch `access token` first.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/

Comment: I already have the access token of the user whose additional info i want to fetch.... the strange things is that it was working till yesterday and all of a sudden something has gone wrong... Is the api that i am using is deprecated?